# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is always empty - PHP

Tags: php, redirect, http-referer

```
<?php
$camefrom =$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ((substr($camefrom,0,26) == "http://www.fromperson.com")
header( 'Location: http://toperson.com' ) ;
?>
```

I need to redirect to www.to.com if the request was made from www.from.com. This code resides in **www.thridperson.com/index.php**

**$camefrom** is always empty.

I have read that $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not reliable. Is there any other way to perform this redirection?

**Note:** I have lost the access to old domain i.e fromperson.com. So, I cannot change this redirection logic it has to be done this way and it has to done only in thirdperson.com/index/php

Comment: Based on your latest edit, I'm afraid you are out of luck. Sorry.

Comment: @Jan Hančič OMG! :( Any work around with Javascript?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the question. Could you detail more on the GET parameter that you mentioned? Could you give a specific example, so that i can follow? - [Pam Apple](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1360660/pam-apple])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No way to do according to my requirement

Answer (score 8):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is indeed unreliable. A client (browser) is not required to include it in the request. If you need a bullet-proof solution that will always work you will have to moddiffy your application on `fromperson.com' to include some GET parameter when linking to your web page, and then you can check if that GET parameter exists and then do the redirect.